# Passing a parameter with a white space

Tags: apache-pig

When I run my script with the command showed below, with `police_force` parameter set as `"Surrey Police"`, it gives me an error

```
"ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. File not found: Police""
```

If I pass in the value as "Surrey_Police" it runs fine but doesn't return anything

```
-- knownvalues: dataset presented
-- date1: one date of comparison
-- date2: 2nd date of comparison
-- police_force: falls within 
-- crime_type
-- Usage: exec -param knownvalues='/user/cw/input/all.txt' -param date1='2017-05' -param date2='2017-06' -param police_force="Surrey Police" /home/xiaorui/CW/compare_crime.pig


knownvalues = LOAD '$knownvalues' USING PigStorage(',') AS (crimeid:chararray,month:chararray,reportedby:chararray,fallswithin:chararray,longitude:float,latitude:float,location:chararray,lsoacode:chararray,lsoaname:chararray,crimetype:chararray,lastoutcome:chararray,context:chararray);


knownvalues = SAMPLE knownvalues 0.00001;

location = FILTER knownvalues BY (fallswithin MATCHES $police_force);

first_date = FILTER location BY (month MATCHES '$date1');

second_date = FILTER location BY (month MATCHES '$date2');

DUMP first_date;
```

If i use the line below, code works as intended

```
location = FILTER knownvalues BY (fallswithin MATCHES 'Surrey Police');
```

Comment: What happens when you enclose it with single quotes? Or use the escape `\` character to escape the space?

Comment: @franklinsijo im not sure I understand what do you mean to use escape character? Single quotes dont change anything

Comment: `-param police_force="Surrey\ Police"`

Comment: still says " ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. File not found: Police"" @franklinsijo

Comment: What version of pig is this?

Comment: Pig 0.16.0 @franklinsijo

Answer (score 0):

I got it achieved with below steps.

a.)Firstly the police_force from filter command should be enclosed in single quotes like below.
location = FILTER knownvalues BY (fallswithin MATCHES **'$police_force'**);

b.) Secondly we need to **include escaping character()** as well **along with either single or double quotes** in execution command.

```
pig -x local -param knownvalues='/home/ec2-user/data' -param police_force="Surrey\ Police" /home/ec2-user/test.pig
or
pig -x local -param knownvalues='/home/ec2-user/data' -param police_force='Surrey\ Police' /home/ec2-user/test.pig
```

Below is my testing code and commands.

**Pig Input data file: cat data**

```
mary,19
john,18
joe,18
Surrey Police,20
```

**Pig Sample Code: cat test.pig**

```
knownvalues = LOAD '$knownvalues' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,age:int);
dump knownvalues;
describe knownvalues;

location = FILTER knownvalues BY (name MATCHES '$police_force');

dump location;
describe location;
```

**Output:**

**After load:**

```
(mary,19)
(john,18)
(joe,18)
(Surrey Police,20)
knownvalues: {name: chararray,age: int}
```

**After filter:**

```
(Surrey Police,20)
location: {name: chararray,age: int}
```